# array of neighbor averages

Tags: numpy, average

What is the function `func` which computes `n-1`-sized array of averages of consequent elements of an array of size `n` (i.e. moving average with window width 2)?

```
func(numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
# return numpy.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for a function here:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x_f2 = 0.5*(x[1:] + x[:-1])
```

If you want it as a function:

```
def window(x, n):
    return (x[(n-1):] + x[:-(n-1)])/float(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.vstack([x[1:], x[:-1]]).mean(axis=0)
```